# Additional data along with TCP connect request

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, winsock

I have a client implementation and a server implementation. I want the client to send data about itself along with its connection request to the server. So for example, I could send an additional packet with the username. I was wondering if this is at all possible using `connect()` before a stream has actually been established. I would then accept only based on that information.

Thanks

Comment: How would that gain you anything? If anything it just brings more pain because you mix layers of the network protocols.

Comment: Not without modifying the underlying protocol.  What's the reason you can't just accept the connection, get a little data at the application layer like normal, and close the connection if you don't like it?

Comment: I was just thinking that I could reject a connection based on a certain username. I guess its a bad idea then.

Comment: @mark I was thinking about that, but would I be able to accept a connection, send data saying why I can't REALLY accept the connection (for example too many clients) and then close it? Is this something I can do in a very minimal amount of time?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea. You want to always establish a connection and THEN start sharing data. For usernames and passwords you should be using secure sockets.

Comment: Sure, you'd "technically" accept the connection, just send data, then close the connection... that'd be pretty fast.  If you're really too busy, you could simply ignore the connection request but you wouldn't know much about it...

Comment: Alright, thanks you guys. I will look into secure sockets Miguel. @Mark I'm going to use that method, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix layers. The TCP `connect` is on the network layer, establishing a communication channel between the machines.

Instead, define your protocol (the rules for how data is transmitted in your TCP stream) to contain a handshake first. E.g. SMTP uses a header and handshake to first set up the connection before any actual emails are sent.